# Why does this JQuery/AJAX call not work?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to implement an autocomplete box ultimately. For now im following php academy's lead. I just want to echo out "suggestions go here" underneath the input area when anything is entered. I have to files. `home.php` and `country.php`. `home` contains the input part and `country.php` just prints the dummy suggestion text. Right now when I type in the input area ..nothing happens. I am using `jquery v 1.6.2` (`jquery-1.6.2.min.js`)

`home.php` is:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src ="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type ="text/javascript">
    function getSuggestions(value){
     #.post("country.php", {countryPart:value}, function(data){
        $("#suggestions").html(data);
      });

    }
   </script>

 </head>

 <body>
    <div id = "content_holder">
       <input type = "text" name="country" value= "" id = "country" onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.value);" />
       <div id ="suggestions"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

`country.php` is

```
<?php

echo "Suggestions Go Here";


?>
```

Comment: are you sure it's "#.post" and not "$.post"?

Comment: A typo? `#.post` instead of '$.post'? If not the case, does the ajax call appear on Firebug?

Comment: I miss a form element? This should give incorrect HTML. Not sure if jQuery bothers, but it can get messy...

Comment: Why do you post the answer as a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Assuming the "#"/"$" is a typo when posting on StackOverflow, check your console for any errors. Is jQuery being loaded from the right location? (`/jquery.js` instead of `jquery.js`). Is it `/country.php` or `country.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wrote

```
#.post
```

should be

```
$.post
```

try that :)

Answer (score 4):

Never seen #.post before... try using $.post

Answer (score 2):

```
$.post
```

not

```
#.post
```

it will work.

if you're working with jquery

```
$.post("country.php", {countryPart:value}, function(data){
        $("#suggestions").html(data);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below code.

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "country.php",
   data: "name=value",
   success: function(data){
     $("#suggestions").html(data);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly using JQuery, you need to change your `post` call to this:

```
$.post("country.php", {countryPart:value}, function(data){
    $("#suggestions").html(data);
});
```

You had `#` instead of `$` before the `post` call.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$.post` and `#.post`

Answer (score 0):

The method name should be
 `$` not `#`

you can use the "console of error"(ctrl + shift + j in monzilla firefox) for check error in javascript/HTML execution